# Ubuntu 11.10 not booting after full install

Tags: installation, boot

I have downloaded and installed the .iso file on a cd using ImgBurn, after which I chose the full installation, erasing everything else on my drives (including Windows 7).

The installation process went down without a hitch. However, when the program tells me the installation is finished and I should reboot the computer and do so, I get a black DOS-style screen with a lot of lines with [ok] behind, and it stalls on 'checking battery charge' or something similar.

I have given it several attempts, all with the same result. I am sure I have followed the instructions during the installation process to the letter, so I am at a loss what is going wrong. I would appreciate any help anyone could give me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. It would boot one out of three times and when it did boot it would crash on opening random apps. For some reason when I reinstalled and **did not** select to do updates or add proprietary drivers during the install, everything went fine and has very since. Hope it helps.